# Razor - to post Url parameters and form data

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have setup a razor page with the following route - i can't figure out how to the the {email} and the {token} sent to my OnPost.

It is always returning as ModelState Invalid and i'm not sure how to fix this.. - any ideas pls? am sure it is something simple i am missing here..

`@page "/ResetPassword/{email}/{token}`

I have the form built as such:

```
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="OnPost">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <input type="hidden" name="Token" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["token"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"]" />
       


        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="VModel.Password" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="VModel.Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="VModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="VModel.ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="VModel.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="VModel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

In the code behind i have:

```
  [BindProperty]
        public ResetPasswordViewModel VModel { get; set; }


  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var result = await _userService.ResetPasswordAsync(VModel);


            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Errors = (List<string>)result.Errors;
                return Page();
            }

        }
```

ResetPasswordViewModel:

```
    public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Token { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength =5)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ***VModel*** before the of your property...

```
  <input type="hidden" name="VModel.Token" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["token"]" />
  <input type="hidden" name="VModel.Email" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"]" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code for token and email

```
       <input  
        id="VModel.Email" 
        name="VModel.Email" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"]" />

       <input  
        id="VModel.Token" 
        name="VModel.Token" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["token"]" />
```